# Laravel AJAX NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, methodnotfound

I've been trying to use the AJAX in my laravel project but it always return an error,

> NotFoundHttpException on RouteCollection.php", "line": 179

My route in web.php is

```
Route::post('/ajaxRequest','AjaxController@index');
```

The controller code is

```
class AjaxController extends Controller {
   public function index(){
      $msg = "Ajax test message";
      return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
   }
}
```

The Ajax call  which I've used is

```
    $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url:'{{url("/ajaxRequest")}}',
             datatype:'json',
             data: pass,
             success:function(data){
                $("#result").html(data.msg);
              }
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                // Handle error here
                $("#result").html(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

and used the meta tag content for csrf_token

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

And retrieved the value using

```
var pass={'_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')};
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Do you have any problem if you call route using route name?

Comment: `'{{url("/ajaxRequest")}}'` - This might not be having the effect you think it should be having if you are in a JS file (external to your blade).

Comment: use `url:'/ajaxRequest',` instead if you have your ajax code in seperate js file as suggested by @Exterminator

Comment: Welcome. Use your browser console/Network tab to make sure the request is correct. You can also use `php artisan route:list` to make sure your route is in the system. (Use `php artisan route:cache` to reload/cache your routes file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change route to this

```
Route::post('/ajaxRequest','AjaxController@index')->name('routeName');
```

and in ajax request make following changes:

```
 $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url:'/ajaxRequest',  //if in js file
             url:'{{route("routeName")}}',  //if in blade file 
             datatype:'json',
             data: pass,
             success:function(data){
                $("#result").html(data.msg);
              }
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                // Handle error here
                $("#result").html(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

Comment: The ajax request is in a js file named ajax.js and the output is set to a blade file

Comment: check the code i have provided the solution for both and if any error occur then please paste the network output screenshot

Answer (score 0):

**Call route using route name**

*Route file*

```
Route::post('/ajaxRequest','AjaxController@index')->name('ajaxRequest');
```

*And your ajax request*

```
 $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url:'{{route("ajaxRequest")}}',
             datatype:'json',
             data: pass,
             success:function(data){
                $("#result").html(data.msg);
              }
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                // Handle error here
                $("#result").html(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```